# Vim: Sudo Edit Breaks Apache Syntax Highlighting

Tags: apache, vim, syntax-highlighting, sudo, vim-syntax-highlighting

Sudo Edit (sudo -e) allows unprivileged users to edit files securely.  To achieve this, it makes a temporary copy of a file to edit and then copies it over when editing is done.

When I'm editing an apache file (eg, /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com), sudoedit vim can't figure out that it should use Apache syntax highlighting, so I have to manually :set syntax=apache.    I suspect that Vim's rule for syntax highlighting relies on the full path of the file, and since sudoedit changes the file to something like /var/tmp/mysiteRANDOMCHARS.com, it loses that path information.

Is there any way for me to automatically tell Vim that it should use apache syntax highlighting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like one of the rare use-cases for the vi modeline feature:

In your `.vimrc`:

```
set modeline
```

And in your Apache config file, somewhere at the top or the bottom:

```
# vi: syntax=apache
```

Comment: I like this, but I'm worried about the security implications of turning modelines on.

Comment: Good point. My only experience with the modeline feature up until now was reading about it. What about https://github.com/ciaranm/securemodelines ?

Comment: Mmm... no comments in the source.  I'll need to read through it before I feel comfortable with it.  But I suspect it'll do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

See `/usr/share/vim/vim7x/filetype.vim` for how Vim determines that a file is an `apache` file.

In my config, using `$ vim` or `$ sudo -e` makes no difference as the `.com` extension is treated as `dcl` anyway.

I don't see a smart and solid way to workaround that beside overriding the `.com` autocommand in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.com set ft=apache
```

Answer (score 0):

Few years late on this post but this did the trick for me:

instead of `-e` which edits I use `-E` which preserves the environment variables and it will run just as if you start `vim` normally.

This however probably not the best approach since we loose the "copy file and edit -> replace" which `sudo -e`/`sudoedit`gives..

however, for my use case it works fine.

tip:

```
# in your shell .rc
export EDITOR=vim
alias sudoe="sudo -E $EDITOR $@"
```